# Taking a detour or choosing a sequence of slides "on the fly"

Tags: beamer, online, pause

I have a beamer presentation to describe a very rough overview of my project, but I abstract out the details. However, I would like to show details on slides in case someone asks me questions. Since I want to decide if I want to show details, on the fly, I want to be able to "press a key" and "take a detour" or activate a sequence of slides.

If I don't press this key then I would like to skip the set of slides (describing the details). Can anyone give me a hint of how I can do this in beamer.

Of course I don't know how this works with a presentation remote, but I guess that is really software dependent and its off context for this forum.

Comment: You can create buttons on the slides, and make them into hyperlinks that point to other frames of your Beamer presentation. For example, in some frame you can add `\hyperlink{<label of another frame>}{\beamerbutton{See details}}`, and then by clicking this button (with a mouse) it'll take you to the frame containing the details.

Comment: Do we get any answer to the question if a `beamerbutton` to jump to the right place and back would be a solution?